# AdMob gives unexpected result while Pop

Tags: ios, objective-c

in my application, i uses AdMob’s Interstitial ad and it is working. but when i pop VC,some times StatusBar becomes hidden and Navigation Crashes.
Situation is When i Pop VC (while,Ad will be presented). otherwise AdMob and Navigation and everything is normally working.

here is my Code for displaying InterstitialAd with its Delegate Methods

```
-viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];

    self.interstitial.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910";

    self.interstitial.delegate = self;

    GADRequest *request2=[GADRequest request];

    request2.testDevices = @[ GAD_SIMULATOR_ID, @"MY_TEST_DEVICE_ID" ];

    [self.interstitial loadRequest:request2];

}
```

Delegate Method

```
- (void)interstitial:(GADInterstitial *)ad didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error
{
    NSLog(@" Error found :-> %@",[error localizedDescription]);
}
- (void)interstitialDidReceiveAd:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial {
    [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
 [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
```

to

```
 [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self.navigationController];
```

Because your ViewController can be popped while an add is being presented, but I hope that your navigation controller is not presented on another ViewController, and can't be dismissed - so the solution will work.